# Jobs not appearing in `jobs`

Tags: linux, jobs

I have a script called `go.sh`

```
python3 bob.py &> lol.log & 
python3 alice.py &> lol2.log &
```

When I run `./go.sh` and then run `jobs`. Neither one of the jobs that I've executed in `go.sh` appear in `jobs`. In fact, nothing appears in `jobs`.

Yet, when I run each command in `go.sh` by one, it does appear in `jobs`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you run `go.sh &` not just `go.sh` and then `jobs`, as this is trivial (no job would be expected to be reported once it's over).

Your script starts two jobs in the background and it's done. So you don't see it. You don't see also the jobs started by the script as it's another shell. If you want to see the jobs, instead of executing the script, source it.

```
. go.sh; jobs
```

Now you should see the two jobs listed.

If you prefer to execute the script and still see it as a job, tell it to wait until its children finish. Add `wait` before its end. You can also call `jobs` from within the script.

Comment: Ah, nice. Makes sense

Answer (score 3):

A job will only appear in "jobs" if it is an immediate child of the shell you're typing at. The script is run in a subshell, in a new process, and so isn't a child of the login shell and isn't visible to the login shell.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to execute a script in the current shell